# Deleting NSManagedObject from core data while another model is using that object

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, concurrency

What should be the proper way to use core data in order to solve the following problem.

I have 2 models.
Model A and model B. both models use the same NSManagedContext (could be part of the problem?)
and a NSManagedObject X.
model A fetches X and starts a timer for 30 seconds. after timer is triggered it does some work on X.
During those 30 seconds model B deletes object X from core data.

Is there a way to keep working on object X with model A after the timer was triggered (including saving the object), or should I just patch a business logic solution that prevents the deletion of X in such case? is there a different architectural solution to this issue that I should be using (parent/child contexts or such)?

Comment: I am not sure that I completely understand your case. Is there a chance that you mean screen (or view controller) instead of model? There cannot be shared object between 2 different models...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be deleting the object if it is still actively being used. Or, when you want to delete it you should be ensuring that all other usage of it is terminated. Logically, what you describe doesn't make sense and I expect you're seeing exceptions when you try to update/save the object that has been deleted.